# How to calculate a price if 3 products are selected and, as a pack, they are cheaper than one at a time

Tags: excel, formula, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator in Excel, which should show the price of the products when the user clicks the item's checkbox.

Example + QUESTION:
If the user selects only item no 1, the price is 45$.
If the user selects only item no 2, the price is 28$.
If the user selects both item no 1 and item no 2, how do I make the price 45$?

In the formula bar I have this:

=IF(A3,45,0)  +  IF(G3,28,0) + IF(AND(A3,G3),45,0)

```
item no 1  item no 2  both items selected
```

But the problem is that the total price is 45 + 28 + 45.

How can I handle this? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Ok, I didn't think it further, here's another situation:

My price calculator looks like this:

```
-voice100      -broadband surf     -TV varied
-voice200      -broadband play     -TV extra
-voice400      -broadband power    -TV max
```

A user can select either one product, or a 2-pack (broadband + TV) or a 3-pack (voice+BB+TV).
Is there any source that could teach me how to do this in excel? (I'll use SpreadSheet Converter to make it HTML/PHP) I want to implement it on a website so that a user can choose his own combination of services and then call me when he's happy with what he chose.

Thank you!

Comment: Check out the MAX function. It might work for you. [MAX Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/max.php)

Comment: @pnuts, thanks! Your first solution worked!
=IF(AND(A3,G3),45,IF(A3,45,0)+IF(G3,28,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works:

```
=IF(AND(A3,G3),45,IF(A3,45,IF(G3,28,0)))
```

Comment: The answer ended up in the low quality queue: and I agree that it lacks the ability to help people in the future because it fails to explain how it solves the problem, only simply solves it. That said, the question it is answering is also low quality. Note the text of the previous comment is default for 'low quality response'.

Comment: Thank you too, @Mike Powell!

But, guys, I have another situation. I didn't think it further when I asked my question.

Please have a look at the original question, I edited it. Thanks!